# Проверить выход за границы массива по принципу DRY

Tags: java, массивы, dry

Есть массив `int[] mas = new mas[size]`. Существует несколько методов:

```
public int getByIndex(int index){...}
public boolean insertByIndex(int number, int index){...}
public int removeFromSlot(int index){...}
```

И в каждом методе есть проверка на выход за границы массива `if(index>=0 && index < size)`
Как записать эту проверку, чтобы не пришлось её прописывать в каждом из 3 методов и тем самым соблюдала принципы DRY.

Comment: Сделайте метод который проверяет массив на наличие такого индекса. и используйте его `boolean checkArrary(int[] arr, int index) { return index>=0 && index<arr.length;}`

Comment: Если ваш метод кидается эксепшынами при выходе за границы, то лучше чтобы `checkArray` был `void` и кидал `IllegalArgumentEcxeption()`. Будет меньше проверок в вызывающем коде, будет удобнее читать код.